# Codename One: How do I define the pressed image for a checkbox

Tags: image, checkbox, codenameone, pressed

In our project, we customized the checkbox(Un)CheckedImage, as shown in below screenshot

[image]
This works fine, but if we press the checkbox, it shrinks and changes color, as shown in the right side of below screenshot

[image]
I cannot find a constant names “checkBoxPressed…”, as indicated below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I contacted Codenameone for help. And I got the answer:

I need to add constants:
checkBoxCheckedFocusImage
checkBoxUncheckedFocusImage

And it worked.

They also asked me to post this question and answer here so it can benefit people who has same question in the future.

Comment: How do you control the size of the checkbox. Or How does it scale automatically. I replaced the checkbox with an svg and png (multi image). They both did not scale per the font size